# Am I reinstalling Edubuntu over a previously corrupt version correctly?

Tags: system-installation, internet, compatibility, edubuntu

I'm trying to salvage a Compaq Evo N600c by reinstalling Edubuntu over the previous version, this time using the LTSP server package. I believe it had the normal version 7.40 from around 2006 or so. The normal startup won't work because it won't recognize the 'kenel' or start through recovery mode. Not knowing any Linux commands right now, I'm simply trying to reinstall the OS through prompts. Not that I'm afraid to use commands, I just don't want to enter the wrong one and end up with an even bigger mess. I ran a memory test with Memtest, on the system and it was fine. I also tested the disk I burnt on the system itself, it was fine. The OS disk was burnt to a .iso file. I used CDBurnerXP on Windows 7. I burnt it to a DVD-R disk formatted through the program.

I first started the disk in developer mode to kinda load everything on the disk. Once I got to the first screen, I restarted the system. This time, I ran the normal install, then began trying to install the new OS (edubuntu-14.04.5-dvd-i386.iso). I selected to overwrite the previous version (7.40 I think), and install the new OS from the disk.

Everything seems to be fine, except I got an error that I clicked 'ignore' to. It was about not enough memory for the OS or something like that. But when I first ran the install, there was a green checkmark next to the line for required amount of space. So, is it talking about the RAM memory or something else? Because I just clicked 'ignore' and it continued the install. I got past the keyboard page, and it's been installing overnight.

I guess my question is: Is the install going to finish or did it stop midway because of an error? It says "The installation will finish soon. We hope you enjoy Edubuntu." I got past the keyboard page, and it's been installing overnight. The cursor keeps spinning too, but I can't hear the disk loading in the drive anymore.

Basically, I'm trying to install the server package on this so I can use this old laptop, stripped, as a mule for making my own internet connection. I selected all the packages, except the pre-k. I managed to get that one before giving up. The double mouse design messed up somehow, and the cursor keeps wanting to go off in some direction. I think water got spilled on it at some point. The sensitivity is also high, so that doesn't help either.

Anyway, I have about 5 older laptops in total. I'm trying to connect them through USB or Ethernet cable to one central laptop 'console'. I'll use that one to manage all the others, creating a multi-system server type of thing. I just had these old laptops around and didn't know what to do with them until I started getting $100 a month internet bills for 16 Mbp/s DL... I might even disable and remove the screens for heat reduction, then connect them all through their back VGA ports onto one screen. The battery on this laptop hasn't been used in a while. It doesn't keep a charge anymore, so I'm running the system of A/C power only. The bar at the top shows it at 25% and charging.

Something I was also considering was wiping the drive with Darik's Boot and Nuke, then reinstalling everything. But that would include the BIOS, all drivers, on top of the new OS, and I'm not really experienced in all that. I know it's trying to install 8 GB, but if it doesn't load before Saturday, I'm going to have to do the backup plan. The mouse keeps moving, but I'm not sure if it's even loading right now.

Thanks for reading, and any advice is appreciated!

Comment: *"But that would include the BIOS, all drivers, on top of the new OS"* - Incorrect. Wiping the disk does not also wipe the BIOS. (If it did, your motherboard would be bricked!) And also, Linux doesn't need external drives. They are all built in. So, I recommended that you download Lubuntu and choose "Erase disk and install Lubuntu" in the installer.

Comment: @Android Dev I was able to dig up an old trackball mouse for the cursor and it seems to work better, though it still pulls up slightly for some reason. I downloaded 'lubuntu-17.04-alternate-i386.iso' and burned it to a new disk, again as a .iso. Thanks for recommending  Lubuntu by the way, I didn't even know it existed. One error I got was that it was unable to read the time clock after selecting install, but it continued fine. I didn't see a prompt for "Erase disk and install Lubuntu", but that could be later on in the OS? (1/2)

Comment: @Android Dev It stayed on a blue and white screen after the first scans it did. Since it stopped here for a while, I just decided to turn it off and run the nuke anyway. If erasing the drive will keep most everything I need, I don't see why not. I'd like to start a new OS fresh. So I'll wait for this to finish, then try testing the disk and install Lubuntu new. (2/2)

Comment: Okay, I wish you luck, be sure to report back whatever happens :)

Comment: @Android Dev "DBAN finished with non-fatal errors" For some reason, it thinks the day is April 17, 2036. That's where I think the time clock error is from. But it didn't save the logs because I don't have a USB stick drive. I'm going to test and run the installation .ios for Lubuntu through the system now, and wait for it to finish. This OS is less than 700 MB, so it should be a lot faster. I found out while it was wiping, that this has a 30 GB hard drive. Oh, I'll keep updating. I I'm still not sure how to configure all the computers to one when I get them all working. Ethernet I hope.

Comment: @Android Dev Okay, it says the CD-ROM is valid. Going to run the install now.

Comment: Great! I think you'll find Lubuntu much snappier and more responsive than Edubuntu :)

Comment: It finished it's setup and took me to a screen to select the primary network interface. I had two options: one, an Intel ethernet controller or two, an 'unknown interface'. Next, to the blank one, it said "irda0". After searching that up, I found out through Ubuntu's Idra how to guide. It "outlines how to get IrDA infrared connections", so I searched that up and found out it has something to do with USB. The first one, enp2s8, looks most legit. The 'autoconfiguration' failed, saying it will result in the network possibly being occasionally slow... (1/2)

Comment: Since I just want to get the OS installed, I opted to not install the network right now. I then set the hostname, username, password, and decided to skip the encryption of the home directory for now. I partitioned the disks next. I changed the 'partition tables' of "SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda), and formatted "partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4." It's installing the base system now. I'll update again soon, and thanks again for the recommendation! It does work a lot better. I might even run .iso's through a virtual box on the other Windows OS laptops. (2/2)

Comment: @AndroidDev Remember how it only runs on A/C power? Well, the port for the thing isn't the best either. I discovered that when I accidentally bumped the cord. It works fine, but I might have to superglue it or something for now if it becomes a problem. I ran the install again and got past it this time. Everything installed fine, and I restarted the system to finalize things. Now for the connection. Do you think I can connect this OS to other Window computers and have it work the same and as I want it to? Should I use virtual boxes? How would that work for a server? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: *"Do you think I can connect this OS to other Window computers and have it work the same and as I want it to? "* - I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @AndroidDev Well, I have four computers in total. Three of them are usable right now.  I want to connect the two up to the main computer, the most powerfull for now until I can fix the fourth...   or should I use the least powerful computer for the base of settings and controls? Is there a way to connect all these to make one server through an ethernet connection or USB somehow? My ultimate goal is to turn all these into one server, for running my own internet connection. I want to eventually control all three with the fourth. (1/2)

Comment: @AndroidDev I couldn't remember the password for the second computer (Compaq Presario CQ61) and tried to recover it. I used Ophcrack with the 'vista_proba_free' pack because the site said it would work with Windows 7. I tried it twice, and both times it froze the computer for an hour. So, I tried some old recovery disks I burnt from another Compaq computer. The problem is, the system said it wasn't recognized. At this point, I've decided to just nuke the hard drive like I did to the Evo, and install Lubuntu fresh. (2/2)

Comment: Wait, so you're aiming to combine the hardware resources of all the machines together to work in parallel?

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes, I'd like to if there's a way.